# Unreal C++ Get Actor Location from Fvector to float

Tags: c++, vector, unreal-engine4

I am looking into how to get spesific actor location such as X, Y and Z location of the Fvector in C++. Main reason is to convert `Row` and `Column` to Vector 2D structure using the `GetActorLoctation()` and the Z location is not effected in this code

[TileToGridLocation in Blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQgmk.png)

[TileToGridLocation within the blueprint code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiXxQ.png)

C++ Code so far:

```
float AGrid::TileToGridLocation(int Row, int Column, bool Center)
{
    return TileValid(Row, Column);
    Row*TileSize+GetActorLocation();//no operator "+" maches float + FVector
    return 0.0f;
}
```

The code is not finished yet, but due to this hicup, I am unable to continue.

```
bool AGrid::TileValid(int Row, int Column)// Validation code. Just a bool check to see if either interger Row or Colum is more then 0. Not afflicted toward the code itself.
{
    if (((Row >= 0) && (Row < NumRows)) && ((Column >= 0) && (Column<NumColumns)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The code makes no sense. You can't `return` twice from a function. Explain what you think each of those lines is doing. You probably want to assert that the tile is valid, not return it; and then return the expression giving the error, or some variant thereof - instead of always 0.

Comment: You should also show the _full_ (minimal) code needed to analyse your question. We don't know what `TileValid()` is, nor what `TileSize` is, nor what `GetActorLocation()` is. It's best to include at least their declarations so that the error can be reasoned about with their types

Comment: TileValid is a separete code that i have implemented in C++. It is not relevant to my question of FVector towards float

Answer (score 0):

`FVector` which is what `GetActorLocation()` returns, has 3 member variables. `X, Y` and `Z`

You cannot simply + a `float` onto an `FVector`, you must + onto each of its members as necessary.

```
float NewX = GetActorLocation().X + SomeFloat;
float NewY = GetActorLocation().Y + SomeFloat;
float NewZ = GetActorLocation().Z + SomeFloat;
```

You can then recompose that into a new `FVector` if you desire.

```
FVector NewVector = FVector(NewX, NewY, NewZ);
```

Also don't use `int` use `int32` instead if you intend your functions, variables to be Blueprint accessible.

Comment: Awsome, this helped alot. Thank you